# Windows 7 and Google Chrome 39.0.2171.65 m

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Since updating Google Chrome a couple of days ago, there is no longer a Print button in the Print function.

In order to print, I have to save  the page as a pdf and then print that out. This is a real nuisance. Is there a more efficient work around? Preferably a return of the print button.

Answer (score 0):

right click -> Print will display the `Print` button ... or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the 'Print' button in the Bookmark bar using the below steps:

Open the Bookmark Manager page > right click the "Bookmarks Bar" and choose "Add Page" > on the right pane of the window, enter 'Print' in the text box and the below query in the 'URL' box > press enter. Now, you should be able to see the Print button the bookmark window.

```
javascript:window.print()
```

[image]

Hope this helps.